# Acesso a módulos diferentes de um departamento

Tags: php, mysql, uml

Estou com uma duvida em uma construção de um pequeno projeto.
Um usuário tem acesso a um módulo de um departamento, até ai tudo bem.
Minha duvida é caso o usuário precise acessar outro módulo do mesmo departamento.
O login está sendo feito automático, eu verifico o acesso ao departamento e ao módulo e tenho uma hierarquia de pasta para departamento com módulos exemplo.

tenho um frontController que chama os includes de acordo com o departamento e módulo. O arquivo include home.php foi exemplo.

```
departamentoA/módulo1/home.php
departamentoA/módulo2/home.php
departamentoA/módulo3/home.php
departamentoB/módulo1/home.php
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tu deves salvar os acessos em uma SESSION, assim tu usa a session para fazer o controle do que pode ou não ser acessado.
A tua pergunta está um pouco difícil de entender exatamente o problema, mas imagino que seja isso...

Comment: @VítorAndré vou refazer a pergunta. Eu gravo na session os ids meu problema e caso o usuario precise de dois modulos como eu chamo includes de pastas diferentes nao conseguiria. Entendeu?

Comment: Mas quando ele acessar o outro módulo ele teria que necessariamente deixar o módulo anterior

Comment: isso mesmo o que sugere trocar o modulo no login

Comment: Acho que tu não tem como evitar voltar a uma pagina de redirecionamento para ir para o modulo novo. A SESSION apenas vai garantir que ao clicar no menu de escolha do módulo tu só exiba as opções válidas e que mesmo que tente burlar pela url ele não consiga acessar um módulo negado.

Comment: @VítorAndré vou repensar as regras de negócio. Pra que o usuário fique amarrado a um módulo apenas e caso precise usar funções de outro modulo eu acrescento ao módulo autal do usuário mediante analise. Talvez o meu problema esteja nas regras de negócios mesmo.

Comment: Esse módulo que tu te refere vai trazer conteúdos para uma mesma página?
O cara poderia estar em uma página x e receber dados de 3 modulos se ele tivesse acesso a eles? É isso?
Se for, tem que vem em que situação tu traria esses módulos (clicando em alguma coisa, enviando um form, sei lá).
eu não entendi o conceito e a finalidade dos módulos.

Comment: @VítorAndré eu tava com uma ideia que caso ele mudasse de setor ele poderia acessar dois modulos entendeu agora? E tipo tem um modulo relatorio e um modulo certificado, ele precisaria estar acessar os dois, mas do jeito que fiz ele não consegue.